Water Radical - with and without
I'm really stumped as to why the Kanji for Leap Year 閏年, where in uru 閏 the water radical 氵is not used  潤

It would be useful if you could explain why you think the water radical should be present.

I have not found the character 閏 without it...unless there is another dictionary that has the character 閏 listed without the water radical...I utilize two dictionaries 1. Kanji Dictionary for foreigners learning Japanese 2500 Kanji and (2). The Kanji Dictionary with over 47,000 compounds By: Mark Spahn and Wolfgang Hadamitzky...I can not find 閏 alone by itself, only with the 氵 water radical.

I know very little about kanji, apart from how to read them in words, so don't entirely trust what I say. In my book "The Kodansha Kanji Learner's Course (2013)" 閏 is not listed among the 2300 joyo kanji. However it does appear in the jinmeiyo kanji list in the same book. Whilst most(?) Japanese words are composed of only the joyo kanji, there are exceptions. I guess 閏年 is one of them.

I think you just need a more comprehensive
kanji dictionary. Here's 閏 in kanjipedia, the online dictionary run by the organization that adminsters the Kanji Kentei. https://www.kanjipedia.jp/kanji/0003259700 You can see on that page that it's a 準１級 level kanji in the Kanji Kentei. That's one level lower than the highest level, which has thousands more kanji within it. １級 covers over 6000 kanji in total.

Much Thanks for the Help & Information user3856370 & Leebo

Arfrever's answer already covered the Japanese aspect(the Yamato-kotoba aspect) of うるい・うるう, but since the question is "why 閏年 and not 潤", I think it's important to delve into the Chinese aspect as well.
Before we start, I'd like to note that native Japanese words developed on their own, and have their own etymologies that's independent from etymologies of Chinese words/characters. Therefore, this answer serves as an addition to Arfrever's answer which already discussed the etymology of the native Japanese words うるい・うるう. We will focus on the Chinese words/characters 閏年 and 潤.
In Chinese, 閏 and 潤 are seen as completely different characters, with completely different meaning. The dictionary give the following definition for 閏:

1.地球公轉一周的時間為365天5小時48分46秒，公曆把一年定為365天，所余的時間約每四年積累成一天，加在2月里；農歷把一年定為354天或355天，所余的時間約每三年積累成一個月，加在某一年里。這在曆法上叫做閏。
2. 姓。



The time for the earth to revolve around the sun is 365 days, 5 hours, 48 ​​minutes and 46 seconds. The Gregorian calendar sets a year as 365 days, and the remaining time accumulates into one day every four years and is added to February; the lunar calendar sets a year as 354 or 355 days, and the remaining time accumulates into one month every three years and is added to a certain year. This is called a leap year in the calendar.
Surname.


Then, for 潤:

1.滋潤；使不乾燥。
2.潮濕；不乾燥。



Moisturize; prevent from drying out.
Moist; prevent from drying out.


We can see that there is ZERO overlap on their meaning in Chinese. 潤 is simply a 形声文字 that uses 閏 as it's sound component. (If you don't know what this is, lookup 六書 or go here)
Dictionary aside, no Chinese speaker will ever make the mental connection that 閏 is related to "moist" or that a leap year is somehow related to being a "moist year". These two are simply different characters that happen to have the same pronunciation, that's all. It just so happens that when the Japanese brought these in, they assigned two readings that's etymologically related to these two Kanji, but in Chinese, their connection is zero, aside from the fact that one contains the other to represent sound.

why the Kanji for Leap Year 閏年, where in uru 閏 the water radical 氵is not used 潤

Back to your question. To answer simply and directly, it's not used because  閏 and 潤 are totally unrelated and have totally different meanings in Chinese, despite their etymologically related Japanese kun-readings.

Appreciate your breakdown, much thanks

General notes:

Most kanji (except e.g. kokuji and Japan-specific simplified forms of kanji) were created in China for words in Chinese languages, and were later imported to Japan.

Japanese people have been assigning kanji for spelling native Japanese words, however ranges of meanings of Japanese words may differ from ranges of meanings of Chinese words spelt with the same kanji.

Words can change their meanings and develop new meanings, and can even develop new usage in different grammatical categories.
E.g. noun */pʲe/ (modern /he/, kanji spelling: 辺) ("place, general area, vicinity") developed into case particle */pʲe/ (modern /e/, hiragana spelling: へ) ("to, towards").
E.g. verb ar- (ある・有る・在る) ("to exist, ...") developed into adjective aru (或る) ("certain, one, some").

Sometimes, diachronically the same Japanese word, depending on its meaning, is spelt with different kanji.
E.g. noun naka (なか) is spelt with either 中 (for "inside, middle, among, during" meanings attested since 712) or 仲 (for "relationship, terms" meanings attested since around 905-914).
E.g. verb tomaru (とまる) is spelt with either 止まる ("to stop, to be stopped") or 泊まる ("to stay at (e.g. hotel), to be docked").

Japanese language historically had somehow more productive usage of prefixes and suffixes for derivation of new words. (Another method of derivation, still productive in modern language, is creation of compound verbs, nouns etc.)
E.g. verb /tuk-/ (付く etc.) + suffix /-ap-/ → verb /tukap-/ (使ふ, modern 使う)
E.g. verb /mor-/ (守る) + suffix /-ap-/ → verb /morap-/ (守らふ, modern 守らう)
E.g. prefix /sa-/ + verb /morap-/ (守らふ, modern 守らう) → verb /samorap-/ (侍ふ・候ふ, modern 侍う・候う)



Notes about 潤 and 閏:

Verb 潤{うるお}う (see also here) had older spelling 潤{うるほ}ふ, and is derived from verb /urup-/:
Verb /urup-/ + suffix /-ap-/ with mutation of vowel → /urupop-/

Noun 閏{うるう} had older spelling 閏{うるふ}, which means that it was /urupu/ in Old Japanese.

https://kotobank.jp/word/閏-35457 says that there was noun うるひ (閏, /urupi/ → /uruwi/ (second half of 10th century is period when non-morpheme-initial /pi/ changed to /wi/ according to Frellesvig)) attested in 古今和歌六帖 from around 976-987, with the same meaning as noun うるふ (閏, modern うるう):



「うるひさへありて行くべき年だにも春に必ずあふよしもがな〈紀貫之〉」


It seems very probable that:

Noun /urupi/ was derived from verb /urup-/ + nominalizing suffix /-i/ (which is mostly homophonous with suffix of Continuative form (連用形) except possibly different pitch accent).

Noun /urupu/ was derived from Attributive form (連体形) /urupu/ of verb /urup-/. In older language, Attributive form was one of several methods of nominalization of verbs.



https://kotobank.jp/word/閏-35457 claims to give example of noun うるふ (閏) from 日本書紀 (720), but this example has usage actually consistent with usage of verbs in attributive function (preceding nouns) or usage of prefixes, and not even with usage of Attributive form (連体形) as noun:



「閏(ウルウ)十一月(しもつき)乙卯(きのとのうの)朔(つひたち)戊午(つちのえむま)に」


Much Thanks for your input
